# How do I avoid particular elements to be added to the browser history?

Tags: javascript, url

I want to avoid `#hash` in the URL to actually be added to the browser history. So each time a new hash is added to the URL, remove it from the history (maybe also from the URL, but that's not the real problem). How can I do that?

*The reason I want to achieve this:* I have a page with a large number of buttons, each on of them triggering a modal and each time one of these buttons is clicked, a hash is added to the URL (and also to the history), so the back button (potentially) needs to be clicked a lage number of times before the browser actually goes to the previous page.

Comment: you want a webpage to modify the content of someones computer?

Comment: may i ask you why you want to achieve sumthin like this, might be helpful information?

Comment: Why does the modal add the hash in the first place?

Comment: @Bergi that's a good question to begin with.

Comment: @Bergi because the modal is triggered by a button with the same href attribute as the id of the modal component. I'm using materializecss framework.

Comment: @Loolooii: So closing the button should just do `history.back` instead of adding a new hash?

Answer (score 0):

You can use history.replaceState(), which change current entry in the session history

```
history.replaceState( {} , 'foo', '/foo' );
```

Comment: Could you be more specific?